# OpenCV overwrites my original image when drawing a line with cv2.line(...)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using `cv2.line(...)` to draw lines over an existing image. I've broken it down into this simple example. I don't understand why the original image is lost on the first call to `cv2.line(...)`, but the same doesn't appear to happen on the second call.

```
# Show the original image (BGR color map)
misc.imshow(vis)

# Draw the first line display, the original image is lost
cv2.line(vis, (10, 10), (300, 300), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=4)
misc.imshow(vis)

# Draw a second line, somehow the previous image wasn't lost this time
cv2.line(vis, (50, 100), (250, 200), color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=4)
misc.imshow(vis)
```

Results from `imshow`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The expected result is the original image with the two lines draw on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because my image was represented as a float32 image with pixel values in the range [0,1], whereas the color was set to (0,255,0), forcing the image to an integer representation which rounded all my [0,1] values to integers.

Changing my color value to (0,1.0,0) fixes the problem.